# First TestFX test executed fails, identical second test passes, when in headless mode

Tags: java, javafx, headless, testfx

I have a problem with TestFX, and running in headless mode on my desktop PC with openjfx-monocle.

Everything was working fine in my first "hobby project" but now when doing this at work I ran into some problems with the main menu that we have.

So the main menu is built up of a MenuBar, which contains Menus and those contains menuItems. Link to image below.

[image: How the menu is built up]

The problem I ran into was when I wanted to open an About dialog, from the main window. This is done by clicking in the MenuBar on the Menu that say 'Help', which displays a dropdown list of menuItems and for the Help Menu we only have the 'About' option right now.

So to the actual problem. I get the error when trying to click on the 'About' MenuItem... so the 'Help' Menu is clickable.

**The error I get is:**

```
org.testfx.api.FxRobotException: the query "About" returned no nodes.
at org.testfx.api.FxRobot.queryVisibleNode(FxRobot.java:1107) at
org.testfx.api.FxRobot.pointOfVisibleNode(FxRobot.java:1076) at
org.testfx.api.FxRobot.clickOn(FxRobot.java:750) at
org.testfx.api.FxRobot.clickOn(FxRobot.java:60) at
se.compenayname.testfx.pages.AboutPage.openAboutDialogFromMain(AboutPage.java:46)
```

Now whats strange to me is that it works great for the next test that gets executed. So if I would create lets say an empty test, or a test which just does an assert for 1+1 = 2 and set it to run first then all tests would pass. - But I dont want to do that, something smells funny and I want to know what I am doing wrong.

Now are there anyone who have had this/similar problems before? or anyone that can help me out, and hopefully just point out some silly newbie misstakes that I've done and send me on my way :)

**Additional information that you might need:**
OS: Windows 7.
Editor: Eclipse.
Gradle version: 3.3. 
JDK : 8u121.

The TestFX and Monocle dependencies in the build.gradle file are:

```
testCompile  "org.testfx:testfx-core:4.0.+", 
             "org.testfx:testfx-junit:4.0.+"
testRuntime  "org.testfx:openjfx-monocle:1.8.0_20"
```

I am note sure if anything else is needed, but I'll give this a try and post this. Apologies beforehand if I am missing something, or if I am unclear in any way.

**The code I am running can be seen below.**

```
public class AboutDialogTests extends TestFXBase{

    private AboutPage aboutPage;

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        aboutPage = new AboutPage(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyCopyrightText(){
        aboutPage.openAboutDialogFromMain();

        FxAssert.verifyThat(AboutDialogFXIDs.COPYRIGHTLABEL, (Label copyrightLabel) -> {
            String text = copyrightLabel.getText();
            return text.equals("Copyright © 1995-2017. CompanyName AB. All rights reserved.");
        }); 
    }
    @Test
    public void verifyCopyrightText2(){
        aboutPage.openAboutDialogFromMain();

        FxAssert.verifyThat(AboutDialogFXIDs.COPYRIGHTLABEL, (Label copyrightLabel) -> {
            String text = copyrightLabel.getText();
            return text.equals("Copyright © 1995-2017. CompanyName AB. All rights reserved.");
        }); 
    }
}
```

**Here is my simple TestFXBase class:**

```
public class TestFXBase extends ApplicationTest{

    private Stage primaryStage;

    /**
     * Am always running in headless mode at the moment.
     */
    static{
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
        System.setProperty("testfx.robot", "glass");
        System.setProperty("testfx.headless", "true");
        System.setProperty("prism.order", "sw");
        System.setProperty("prism.text", "t2k");

    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
         this.primaryStage = stage;
         primaryStage.show();
    }


    @Before
    public void beforeEachTest() throws Exception{
        /*
         *  The following FxToolkit lines allow for indirectly performing
         *  ApplicationTest.launch(Main.class); and registering the primary stage
         *  in order to allow running multiple @Test in a single file
         */
        FxToolkit.registerPrimaryStage();

        // specifying which class to start the application with.
        FxToolkit.setupApplication(Main.class); 
    }


    /**
     * Release any keys and mousebuttons that may be stuck so that it wont influence other tests.
     * @throws TimeoutException
     */
    @After
    public void afterEachTest() throws TimeoutException{
        FxToolkit.hideStage();
        release(new KeyCode[]{});
        release(new MouseButton[]{});
    }
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }
}
```

**And here is the AboutPage class:**

```
public class AboutPage{
    private final TestFXBase base;

    public AboutPage(TestFXBase fxBase) {
        this.base = fxBase;
    }


    /**
    * Navigate through the main menu and open the 'About' dialog.
    */
    public void openAboutDialogFromMain() {
        base.clickOn("Help").clickOn("About", Motion.VERTICAL_FIRST, MouseButton.PRIMARY);

    // The lines below does not work at all when trying to click on a menu / menuitem.
    //base.clickOn(MainMenuFXIDs.MAINMENUHELP);
    //base.clickOn(MainMenuFXIDs.HELPMENUITEMABOUT);
    }


    public void closeAboutDialog() {
        base.clickOn(AboutDialogFXIDs.CLOSEBUTTON);
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: I rewrote my question somewhat and posted it on the TestFX Issues page on Github. Still no reply at the time of writing this comment, but if my question above is unclear in any way then this might hopefully be easier to understand, I hope. https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/issues/406